# Install libc >= 2.24 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux

I need to install the libaio1 on ubuntu 16.04. The problem is that this package depends on libc6 >=2.24 and i can't install it because libc6 2.23 is already installed. The error message is 
libc6:amd64 casse (« breaks ») locales (<< 2.24)
  « locales » (version « 2.23-0ubuntu4 ») .
How can I upgrade it?

Comment: The [official *libaio1* package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libaio1) doesn't depend on libc6 >= 2.24.

Comment: @nwellnhof Ok thanks.